# matrix multiplication of a nested dictionary storage and a 1d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

so I want to do a basic matrix multiplication A by x, so Ax = b
but A is a "dictionary" containing a sparse matrix (only entries that are not zero are given) and x is a 1d numpy array. so for example

```
A = {0: {2: 2, 3: 3}, 1: {3: 5}, 3: {1: 10}}
```

visually it looks like

```html
<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$$\begin{bmatrix}&space;0&space;&&space;0&&space;2&space;&&space;3\\&space;0&space;&&space;0&space;&&space;0&space;&&space;5\\&space;0&&space;0&space;&&space;0&space;&&space;0\\&space;0&&space;10&&space;0&&space;0&space;\end{bmatrix}$$" title="$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0& 2 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 5\\ 0& 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 10& 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$$" />
```

and x is a 1d numpy array so

```
x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1]) #x1 x2 x3 x4
x
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

in the end i want the result Ax to also be a 1d numpy array (A is 4 by 4 and x is 4 by 1 so A*x has to also be 4 by 1). so the output should be

```
Ax = np.array([5, 5, 0, 10])
```

is there a way to do matrix multiplication of A in the correct order given only the sparse matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution uses sparse matrices in coordinate format from scipy (see [coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)):

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

rows, cols, data = zip(*[(row, col, A[row][col]) for row in A for col in A[row]])
coo = coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)))

>>> coo.toarray()
array([[ 0,  0,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0,  0]])

coo.dot(x)
>>> array([ 5,  5,  0, 10])
```

The second solution uses python and numpy only for NaNs and to hold the final array:

```
rows = range(min(A.keys()), 1 + max(A.keys()))

result = []
for row in rows:
    row_data = A.get(row)
    result.append(sum(A_val * x[col]
                      for col, A_val in row_data.iteritems())  # .items() for Python 3
                  if row_data else np.nan)
Ax = np.array(result)

>>> Ax
array([  5.,   5.,  nan,  10.])
```

Comment: with regards to the second solution, it works if A is an n by n matrix but not for m by n matrix. e.g if A is a 5 by 4 matrix and x stays the same. Ax would be a 5 by 1 matrix, but your np.array(result) is still a 4 by 1 array.

Comment: You are correct.  I just amended the solution to fix that issue.

Comment: where you said "# .iter() for Python 3"  i think you meant  ".items()" and not .iter() right?

Comment: Constructing a `lil_matrix` is a little faster (for this small case), and may be a bit more intuitive.